# Selecting a class within an id

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

this is probably a noob question but I want to select the link via css. $page being returned is just a number being passed in and not a big deal. I want to select the class "link1".  Here is the html code.

```
    echo '<ul id="navlist">
<li><a class:"link'.$page.'" href="index.php?page=1">Home</a></li>
<li><a class:"link'.$page.'" href="index.php?page=2">Shoes</a></li>
<li><a class:"link'.$page.'" href="index.php?page=3">Drills</a></li>
<li><a class:"link'.$page.'" href="index.php?page=4">Top Player</a></li>
<li><a class:"link'.$page.'" href="index.php?page=5">Contact Us</a></li></ul>
```

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, using `class:` doesn't work. You need to use `class=`. Second, the classes will all be the same (e.g. `link1`). You need to write some php code using at least one array and a for(){} loop to do what you really want. If all your classes en up being `link1` then Luke Peters' answer is correct.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP. Also post the CSS you tried

Answer (score 4):

Well first thing that jumps out to me is that your code has "class:" instead of "class=". That's almost certainly not going to be parsed correctly.

With regard to "selecting" the link, I'm assuming you mean for a style sheet so you can add some styles to it? In that case the CSS selector would be:

```
#navlist .link1
```

Answer (score 2):

So, if I understand what you want to do.. In your CSS you can target those links like this:

```
.link1 {
    color: red;
}
```